# Как сохранить инфу с формы в txt файл?

Tags: php, html, jquery, bootstrap

Всем привет!
В общем задача такая, что где-то, я криво получаю с формы данные, которые не могу записать в файл.

Есть html file

```
<div class="modal fade" id="sendMsgToPhp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <form>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="theme">Тема</label>
                            <input type="text" name="theme" class="form-control" id="theme" placeholder="Тема">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="time">Время</label>
                            <input type="text" name="time" class="form-control" id="time" placeholder="Время">
                          </div>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Отправить</button>
                          <div class="success" style="display: none;">
                            <p>Добавлено!</p>
                          </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Принимаем с jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#sendMsgToPhp").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../php_scripts/update.php",
        data: $("#sendMsgToPhp").serialize(),
        success: function () {
            $('.success').delay(600).fadeIn(1000);
        }
    });
}); });
```

Теперь записываем в файл через php

```
<?php 
$theme = $_POST['theme'];
$time = $_POST['time'];

$today = $theme . " " . $time;
$fh = fopen("testfile.txt", 'r+') or die("Сбой открытия файла");
fseek($fh, 0, SEEK_END);
fwrite($fh, $today) or die("Сбой записи в файл");
fclose($fh); ?>
```

Comment: Так в чем ошибка-кривость?

Comment: Просто данные не записываются, которые я отправляю)

Comment: попробуйте после переменной $today написать `echo $today; `// что-нибудь отобразилось?

Comment: пробовал, пустота, а в блокнот пихает пустую строку (ибо нечего принять с post'a)

Comment: Если "$today" равно пустой строке, значит данные не присылаются. Что пишется в консоли браузера при отправке формы?

Comment: ничего абсолютно. проверил в network, он действительно отправляет в файл update.php.

Comment: #sendMsgToPhp это div.у него нет события submit. Вешайте событие на форму

Comment: спасибо, добавил id форме, зацепил в jquery...и заработало..

Comment: Один из тех вопросов, которые мы все так ненавидим: в заголовке одно, а в тексте и в ответе совсем другое. Мужчина. Если у вас проблема с отправкой текста яваскриптом, **то так и надо писать!** И не сбивать с толку **тысячи людей** которые ищут ответ на вопрос "как записать в файл"

Answer (score 0):

Записать текст из формы не просто, а очень просто. Это всего лишь одна функция.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['theme'])) {
    file_put_contents("testfile.txt", $_POST['theme']);
}
```

Если текст надо не заменить полностью, а добавить к существующему, то использовать предназначенный для этого флаг

```
file_put_contents("testfile.txt", $_POST['theme'], FILE_APPEND);
```

Примечание: если вам так сложно дается яваскрипт, то надо отказаться от него. И отправлять форму обычным способом, без всякого яваскрипта. Это решит вашу текущую задачу и позволит двигаться дальше.

В случае же, если проблема именно с отправкой, то *этот вопрос и надо задавать*: "у меня проблемы с отправкой формы аяксом". А не "Как записать в файл".

Answer (score -1):

```
$(this).serialize() либо $('#sendMsgToPhp form').serialize()
```

вместо

```
$("#sendMsgToPhp").serialize()
```